# I'm not managing to download from CTAN. How can I select the mirror I use?

Tags: packages, ctan

Yesterday I was stumped while not managing to download any package from [CTAN](http://www.ctan.org/). While I could navigate and browse the directories, any time I selected a file to download the request would time-out. A web search reveled nothing. No-one else seemed to have the same problem, and I was stumped. After while, I realized that CTAN is distributed on many mirrors across the globe and most likely the actual downloading is undertaken by an automatically selected mirror. What I didn't manage to find out was how to control the mirror I am downloading from.

So: my questions are:

> How can I download a file from CTAN from a manually selected mirror rather than the automatically selected one? How can I find out which mirror is automatically selected for me?

I guess I could use this as a platform to suggest a possible improvement to the powers (at CTAN.org) that be: Add a little randomization to the mirror selection algorithm. Even if you don't know whether the best mirror for me is up or down, if you have 5 mirrors close to me, I don't need the closest one all the time, I'd rather not risk getting stuck with a broken mirror for 12 hours...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This list might help you: [CTAN mirrors](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/CTAN.sites).

At least you could select a mirror and browse. The standard CTAN search engine might help a bit if the mirror server itself doesn't offer a search feature. Another option, helpful in general, is to use a search engine like google with the `site:` option.

Comment: And if ctan.org is not working, you can use one of the other two main sites: http://dante.ctan.org/search.html and http://www.tex.ac.uk/

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to change the automatic mirror because it was too slow. So I did the following to change the mirror:

1. Downloaded the installer
2. In the installation folder, traverse to \install-tl-\tlpkg\TeXLive\TLConfig.PM
3. Open the file in any text editor and change the value of the parameter: 
   our $TeXLiveServerURL = .
4. Save the file, close it and start the installer :-)

Comment: @Krishna, thanks for the answer, but I think the question was about the mirror used by the CTAN *website*, not a particular TeX installation.